# Limiting number of clicks on a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have two buttons on my webpage(Accept And Reject). I want to restrict the number of clicks on the accept button. I want the number of times Accept button can be clicked to be 20 times over a period of 24 hours. Once 24 hours finish, the user can click the button again for 20 times. I am using a MySQL database and PHP.

Comment: What have you done so far? Any code? Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Use a counder mechanism and settimeout to achieve this.

Comment: whats that Accept button is all about.

Comment: It is a dating site like tinder. Where a user can accept or reject a person. I haven't started coding this, because I am not able to get started with it.

Answer (score 6):

Basically I have no any idea about PHP but I can suggest the way that might be needful to achieve your result.

**You need one table with certain columns as given below.**

1. UserId int PK
2. FirstClickDateTime DateTime
3. TotalClicks int

**Create a store procedure that perform the operations including Insert, Update according to condition as following.**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_ManageButtonClickByUserId
      @UserId INT,
      @IsClick BIT = 0
    AS BEGIN

-- Lets consider your table name is ManageButtonCLick with columns including 
-- 1.UserId int
-- 2.FirstClickDateTime DateTime
-- 3.TotalClicks int

IF ISNULL(@IsClick,0) <> 0 -- Determine IsClick is true when pass from code
BEGIN
    Declare @TotalClick AS INT
    SET @TotalClick = (SELECT TotalClick FROM ManageButtonCLick WHERE UserID = @UserId);
    SET @TotalClick = ISNULL(@TotalClick, 0) + 1;


    If EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ManageButtonCLick WHERE UserID = @UserId) -- If user exists than update record
    BEGIN

        /* Determine the 24 is completed or not for specific user */
        Declare @IsHoursCompleted AS BIT = 0; -- Indecates false
        Declare @TotalHoursCompleted AS INT = 0;

        SET @TotalHoursCompleted = (SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, FirstClickDateTime, GETDATE()) FROM ManageButtonCLick WHERE UserID = @UserId);
        SET @IsHoursCompleted = (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(@TotalHoursCompleted,0) >= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);

        IF (ISNULL(@IsHoursCompleted,0) <> 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ManageButtonCLick
            SET FirstClickDateTime = GETDATE(), TotalClicks = 1
            WHERE UserID = @UserId
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE ManageButtonCLick
            SET TotalClicks = @TotalClick
            WHERE UserID = @UserId
        END
    END
    ELSE -- if user not exists than insert that user detail for button click
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ManageButtonCLick (UserId, FirstClickDateTime, TotalClicks)
        VALUES (@UserId, GETDATE(), @TotalClick)
    END
END
END
```

**Now this time to manage clicks from code behind**

When user load this page(which has Accept button at that time you need to determine that user has completed the total clicks within 24 hour. For this task, you have to create one function that return true or false).

**If** button is enable for specific user than perform below operation...

When user click on "Accept" button, You need to call the procedure from your code along with required parameters.

**Else** button is disabled for this user.

Answer (score 0):

- Add an `onclick EventListener` to the `button`.
- Set a global variable as counter.
- For each click, increase the count.
- While it reaches 20, add a setTimeout to reset the counter to 0 with time span 86400000 ( 24 hrs in milliseconds).

Check the code below. (click 20 times)

```js
var times=0;
function checkTime(btn){
  if(times<20){
     ++times;
  }
  else{
    btn.disabled=true;
    console.log("come back tomorrow");
    setTimeout(function(){ times=0; }, 86400000);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkTime(this);">Accept</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like @SagarV proposes because then a user can just reload the page and continuing spamming the button. You need to set a flag or something in the sessionStorage or a cookie to be able to prevent user to click the button in in 24h period.

Comment: Can you provide me with some kind of code. It would be really helpful.

Comment: Im not sure how your application work, but use the counter as proposed above, and when the limit is reached, then set a cookie for that user like document.cookie = "username=Bill Bull; expires=Sat, 25 March 2017 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

Comment: or use the sessionStorage on the window object, problem with this is that if a user opens a new tab, then its a new session.

Comment: But with the cookie,  if a user does not have a cookie or if it has expired, the user can click the button again else not.